# Angular 8 - Notify navbar component about the changes in other component

Tags: angular

In index.html I have

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

Here is app.component.ts and app.component.html

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
------------------------------------------
<nav-menu></nav-menu>

<div class='container-fluid'>
   <div class='row justify-content-center'>
      <div class='col col-md-4 body-content'>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </div>
 </div>
```

In this legacy code as you can see NavMenu component isn't the part of routing system.
So what I'm trying to do is to keep information about if the user is logged-in or not in NavMenu component via userService-a.

Here is NavMenu code navmenu.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from './../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-menu',
  templateUrl: './navmenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navmenu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  loggedIn;

  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedIn = this.userService.isloggedIn;
  }

}
```

And service part

```
 public get isloggedIn(): boolean{
    return localStorage.getItem('token') !==  null;
  }
...
```

So when a user logged-in in LoginComponent.

```
 onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.login(form.value).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
      },
...
```

I need changes to be reflected at the moment of login in NavBar component, but NavBar component isn't reloaded so the changes are visible only after I manually reload the page. Is there any way to somehow notify NavMenu component about the changes (to reload NavMenu)?

Comment: from where you want to generate event?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rxjs/Subject` for this. `Subject` can notify your components about changes.

Create a subject where you want to create notification, then subscribe to that `Subject` in any component as required.

When you call `next` on `Subject`, it will trigger the callback in subscribed component.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ervknf) (Notice how value changes from service in AppComponent)

**Service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  isLoggedInSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
  isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor() {
    this.someServiceLogic();
  }

  someServiceLogic() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.isLoggedIn = !this.isLoggedIn;
      this.isLoggedInSubject.next(this.isLoggedIn);
    }, 2000);

  }
}
```

**Component**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.dataService.isLoggedInSubject.subscribe(status => {
      this.isLoggedIn = status; // your emitted value is received here.
    })
  }
}
```